# C++ constexpr type ID

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, constexpr, typeid

I notice that the `typeid(T)` call provides a nice constexpr-compatible way to retrieve a unique identifier for a given class at compile-time. This is very useful, but I notice that relational operators between the `type_info` objects which this yields are not enabled at compile-time. This makes sense, since the actual IDs may vary at runtime. However, I would like to impose an ordering between types such that:

1. Every type has some unique ID which is generated at compile-time. It does *not* matter what these IDs are, or how they are ordered between classes.
2. For each pair of types, the IDs between the types can be compared relationally to determine which type has the "lesser" ID.
3. It **does not** matter if the order of the IDs changes between compilations.

This is very doable at compile-time by explicitly defining the IDs for each type. However, I was wondering if there is a more reasonable approach to generate compile-time, constexpr-compatible IDs per type which allow for relational operations.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm curious why you need compile-time comparison...

Comment: Essentially, an implementation of an unordered tuple. For example, unordered_tuple<B,A> should have an underlying representation compatible with unordered_tuple<A,B>.

Comment: So, like [`boost::fusion::set<>`](http://www.boost.org/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/container/set.html)? (Boost.Fusion overview [here](http://www.boost.org/libs/fusion/).) If so, this is rather an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/166663). ;-]

Comment: The desired usage seems pretty similar to the `fusion::set<>`! Based on my experience with sets, though, they traditionally indirect to heap memory, whereas tuples are fully contained on the stack (but I admit to not knowing much about the Boost implementation, so please correct me if I'm wrong!) Essentially, the 'Y' in this XY problem is that I'd like a uniform function which can take an `Object<A>,` add a `<B>` to it, and add it to a vector of `Object<A, B>`'s. Similarly, I'd like to take an `Object<B>`, add an `<A>`, and still map to the `Object<A,B>` vector. In any case, thanks a ton :]

Comment: Boost.Fusion makes no heap usage, its set (as with all its containers) is just a glorified tuple. /*I'd like a uniform function which can take an `Object<A>`, add a `<B>` to it, and add it to a vector of `Object<A, B>`*/ Fusion does exactly this. See the section on mutating functions/metafunctions.

Comment: That is incredible, in that case, I think you've solved the "X" from my original "Y". Thanks a ton! (now to take a peek into the source to see how it's done :P )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>Summarizing comments:</sup>

[`boost::fusion::set<>`](http://www.boost.org/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/container/set.html) has the functionality you need, with metafunctions to mimic most algorithms in the standard library, including insertion and removal. All Fusion containers are completely stack-based, as all are simply tuples with algorithm metafunctions on top.

<sub>(Boost.Fusion overview [here](http://www.boost.org/libs/fusion/).)</sub>